# Where is $|xy|$ function differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Let $f(x,y) = |xy|$. Find the sets of all points $(x,y) \in \Bbb R$  where $f$ is differentiable and compute the differential in those points.

Can someone explain me how to show differentiability?

Thanks!

Comment: (and $g(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but it is weak-differentiable, since $g(x) = \int_0^x sign(t) dt$)

Comment: Should be $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value function $\lvert . \rvert$ is not differentiable at $0$, because the limit of the difference quotient from the left is $-1$ and from the right $1$. A similiar behaviour will show up in your function $f$ for points $(x,y)$ with $xy = 0$.

[image: xy]
[image: abs(xy)]

([Large version left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjZuW.png), [large version right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeGOi.png))

The left image shows $g(x,y) = xy$ (green hyperbolic surface), the right image shows $f(x,y) = \lvert xy \rvert$ (red surface). The negative valued parts got "folded" upwards by the absolute value function.

If you align tangential planes to the red surface you see that you have two choices for the points $xy = 0$ except for the origin.

E.g. if we keep $x$ constant we have
$$
f(x,y) = \lvert x y \rvert = \lvert x \rvert \, \lvert y \rvert = c(x) \lvert y \rvert
$$
so the $V$ shapes turn less and less steep for $x \to 0$ and two choices turn into one along $x=0$.

Comment: "A similar behaviour ... _except possibly_ (and actually) _at the origin_." :)

Comment: But how do you show it mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy. It is differentiable on the 4 open quarters of the plane, that is on

1) $]-\infty,0[ \times ]-\infty,0[$

2) $]-\infty,0[ \times ]0,\infty[$

3) $]0,\infty[ \times ]-\infty,0[ $

4) $]0,\infty[ \times ]0,\infty[$

Indeed, on these 4 open domains, $f$ coincides with a polynomial function ($(x,y)  \mapsto xy$ and $(x,y)  \mapsto -xy$ are indeed polynomial), so $f$ is differentiable.

Assume that we are on the domain number $1$ or the domain number $4$. On these domains, we have $f(x,y) = xy$, so can compute the differential of $f$ by writing:

$$f(x+h,y+k) = (x+h)(y+k) = xy + kx + hy + hk = f(x,y) + kx + hy + o(h,k) $$

The application $(h,k) \mapsto kx + hy$ is a linear application, so the development above proves that it is the differential of $f$. Therefore $df(x,y)\cdot(h,k) = kx + hy $.

On the domains $2$ and $3$, we have $f(x,y) = -xy$, so we find $df(x,y)\cdot(h,k) = -(kx + hy) $

It's more tricky when you get on the x-axis or the y-axis. Here, the idea is to prove that $f$ is not differentiable by proving that it is not differentiable over one direction.

For example, let's say $(x,y)$ is on the right half of the $x$-axis, i.e at the point (x,0) with $x>0$. We have $f(x,y)=f(x,0) = 0$ (obvious), and now, if we compute the derivative over the $y$-axis:

we compute $\frac{f(x,y)-f(x,0}{y} = x \frac{\vert y \vert}{y}$, which is equal to $x$ if $y > 0$, and to $-x$ if $y<0$. So this quantity does not have a limit when $y \rightarrow 0$. Therefore $f$ is not differentiable in the direction $(0,1)$ at this point, so $f$ is not differentiable at the point $(x,0)$.

Same reasoning holds for the 3 other "half-axis".

Comment: but how you show that it is differentiable at (0,0)

Comment: at $(0,0)$, you have $f(h,k)= \vert hk \vert = 0 + o(h,k)$ so it is differentiable with a differential equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

By Young's inequality,
$$
2 |xy| \leq x^2+y^2
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
and hence $Df(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've seen this in class too, but I can't connect this approach to showing that the function is differentiable. I mean why can I say this by what you've written? 
I've seen that in order to show differentiability I've to use:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\frac{|f(x) - f(x_0) - A(x-x_0)|}{|x-x_0|}$

Comment: @Ergo I proved that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\|(x,y)\|} =0,$$ so that $A=Df(0,0)=0$ by definition.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_0y_0\ne 0$ then $f(x,y)=|xy|=xy\vee |xy|=-xy$ in some neibourhood of the point of  $(x_0;y_0)$ and so the function is differenciable at $(x_0;y_0)$.

If $x_0y_0= 0$, say $x_0=0$ and $y_0\ne 0$, then does not exist $\frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x}$ because does not exist derivative of $|x|$ at $0.$

If $x_0=y_0=0$ then $\frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial y}=0$ and we must verify that $|xy|=o(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ under the definition of differentiability at $(0;0).$  This is true because $2|xy|\le x^2+y^2  $.